# How to upload multiple files using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, angularjs

I have 5 upload files here, [image] , now I am trying to figure out how to send it to the db  after I convert it to base64, the problem is I don't know how to attach it to `attachment_id`. [image]

Comment: Please provide code snippets along with your issue. We can't help you without that.

Comment: Sorry but I' don't have snippets for that because I'm still figuring it out how to implement, I'm hoping that someone can suggest or give advice the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

actually i dont really know the exact question, but hope this would help

if you want to send files to your own db you can use `formData`, it helps you to send it to server

about the `attachment_id`, i think you can use random string or simple counter to make your file has unique